# Why doesn't IXMLNode.IsTextElement return True for CDATA elements?

Tags: xml, delphi, delphi-2007

We're using Delphi 2007 and the `oxmldom` `Open XML` provider.

A normal situations input file looks similar to this:

```
<root>
  <child>Some Text</child>
</root>
```

Now we have to process an input file that uses the `CDATA` node type:

```
<root>
  <child><![CDATA[Some special Text]]></child>
</root>
```

`Node.IsTextElement` suddenly returns `False`, but `Node.Text` still works as expected.

I know that `IXMLNode.IsTextElement` is just a convenience method, but I find this behavior rather odd.

As a workaround we're now using this custom method:

```
class function TXmlUtils.IsTextOrCDataElement(ANode: IXMLNode): Boolean;
begin
  Result := False;
  if ANode.ChildNodes.Count = 0 then begin
    if ANode.NodeType in [ntText, ntCData] then begin
      Result := True;
    end;
  end else
  if ANode.ChildNodes.Count = 1 then begin
    if ANode.ChildNodes.First.NodeType in [ntText, ntCData] then begin
      Result := True;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

My question is: Why does `IsTextElement` not work with `CDATA` nodes and is there an easier workaround?

Comment: But... a CDATA element is *not* a TEXT element, so this behaviour is correct. Your work around seems not to be a work around at all but an implementation the correct behaviour you expect.

Comment: @RitsaertHornstra: you should post that as an answer to get credit for it.

Comment: So the `Text` property works on different types of nodes and the `IsTextElement` only looks for nodes of type "TEXT"? Is that correct?

Comment: But @Ritsaert, IsTextElement method *also* returns True for non-text nodes. Specifically, it returns True for elements that have a single text-node child, such as `<child>` in the example above. So, since it already differs from a simple `is` or `Supports` test, Jens's question of why it doesn't return True for *other* text-like nodes is legitimate.

Comment: @Rob Kennedy - In `IsTextElement` there is `Element` word. And <child> is `Element` which contains `Text` node. Literally, for me everything is fine with this function.

Comment: @Pol, IsTextElement returns true when called on an element that contains a single text node, but it also returns True when called directly on the text node, in which case there is no *element* at all.

Comment: @Rob Kennedy, parent of text node is element.

Comment: @Pol: However there is no method like IsTextOrCDataElement, so that makes the IsTextElement function less useful. From a practical PoV there should have been a "TextAvailable" method. So My question is more like "Why is there no TextAvailable method?".

Comment: @Jens Mühlenhoff - Of course I agree with 'there should have been a "TextAvailable" method'

Comment: Does it make sense to QC this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't return true for Cdata nodes because that's just not the way it was written. It's unfortunate because consumers of XML data generally shouldn't be concerned with *how* text is represented in the serialized data. Your alternative is fine.

Comment: I accepted this answer, because it confirms that I'm doing the right thing and that the `IsTextElement` is indeed insufficient for our requirements.

Answer (score 1):

As Ritsaert Hornstra wrote in comment CDATA is not TEXT node of DOM tree. It's CDATA node.

Text property is something different. E.g. when current node is an attribute, Text will probably return value of this attribute.

If you want to check if current node is CDATA node or TEXT node, simply use Delphi `is` operator. There is also something like `nodeType` property which you are using anyway :-)

Comment: +1 because your answer is technically correct, but practically I was missing something like a "IsTextAvailable" method (see comments to the question).

Answer (score -1):

If you want to check if current node is CDATA node or TEXT node, simply use Delphi `is` operator. There is also something like `nodeType` property which you are using anyway :-)

```
? XML CDATA read
```