# How can I get the Open XML DOM parser to parse an ntEntityRef node?

Tags: xml, delphi, delphi-2007

I have this XML input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string>
&lt;N/A&gt;
</string>
```

Here is a short code sample to illustrate the problem:

```
uses
  xmldom, oxmldom, XMLDoc, XMLIntf;

procedure TForm1.Test;
var
  Document     : IXMLDocument;
  StringNode   : IXMLNode;
  LessThanNode : IXMLNode;
begin
  DefaultDOMVendor := 'Open XML';
  Document         := LoadXMLData(Memo1.Lines.Text);
  StringNode       := Document.DocumentElement;
  LessThanNode     := StringNode.ChildNodes.First;
  ShowMessage(LessThanNode.Text); // Displays '' (an emtpy string)
  ShowMessage(LessThanNode.XML);  // Displays '&lt;'
  ShowMessage(StringNode.Text);   // Causes an EXMLDocError, because the string node contains more than just a single node with NodeType = ntText
end;
```

How can I get the `Open XML` parser to transform the `&lt;`, `&gt` and similar XML entities to their real text (like `<` and `>`)?

I could write a workaround for the predefined entities in the XML specification:
http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#sec-predefined-ent

That won't help with additional entity nodes though ...

Related: [Why doesn't IXMLNode.IsTextElement return True for CDATA elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8416986/why-doesnt-ixmlnode-istextelement-return-true-for-cdata-elements)

Comment: Did you tried to validate document using OpenXML?

Comment: @Pol - why would he want to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Newer versions of Delphi don't ship the oxmldom unit anymore and newer versions of the so called ADOM are available:

http://www.philo.de/xml/downloads.shtml

So either using a different parser or upgrading OpenXML solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In your case I think the `InnerText` property should work.

```
ShowMessage(Document.DocumentElement.InnerText);
```

**Edit:** The `InnerText` property is not part of the `IXMLNode` interface (I think MSXML has it.) The OpenXML implementation (ADOM) has a `GetTextContent` method that probably does the same thing, so you may want to look into it.

Comment: There is no `InnerText` in `IXMLNode` (at least in D2007). Unless I'm missing something here?